# How do i use grails tags in JSP

Tags: jsp, grails, gsp

I have a JSP file which i am including in my GSP

```
 <div class="dialog">
                <g:include view="WEB-INF/-----/merchantCompany.jsp"/>
            </div>
```

and in my merchantcompany.jsp i need to include timezone as drop down. Since grails has g:timezone i want to use that tag. How can I include grails tag-lib in my jsp??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Following

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://grails.codehaus.org/tags" prefix="g" %>

<g:form method="post" controller="book">
</g:form>
```

This is more or less same as way in which you will use any oither taglib in jsp files.

Hope that helps.